# Changing image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a menu consisting of images and the images should change when someone hover around it.

### HTML

```
<div id="menu" >  
    <a href="#" id="home"><img  src="images/about.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#menu {
        margin-left    : 353px;
        margin-top     : -70px;
        padding-bottom : 16px;
}

#home {
        background     : transparent url(images/about.png);
        z-index        : 1;
}

#home:hover {
        background     : url(images/aboutR.png);
        z-index        : 2;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I **hover** around the menu item, the image to be displayed on hover is displayed **at the back of** the old image. Moreover, the hover background image displayed is **very small** in width and height. Please help out. Thanks

Comment: You should look into doing this with javascript instead.

Comment: @Shredder, why is JavaScript preferred over CSS Sprites?

Comment: yes. You could go with plain javascript but jquery will be easier. You'll be able to map efficiently your effects, actions, and so on. With css you would only look for things bordering hacks but menu and navigation end to be much more than just images on hover.

Comment: I read a good article about it, it [here](http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/changing-html-images-on-hover/)

Comment: Just Google ["CSS Sprites"](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=CSS+Sprites&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"The orange one(About Us) is the hover image..."_ - I don't see anything orange.

Comment: @Sparky672 It might be easier with OPs markup to switch out the img source with js events.

Comment: Are you open to js/jQuery solutions?

Comment: @Shredder: Yes, I think I should go for jQuery. Would have to read a little. I have done jQuery but its been a while.

Comment: @Shredder: Thanks for mentioning jQuery. Just did that with jQuery. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this code just before the closing body tag,

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".home").hover(
        function() {$(this).attr("src","images/aboutR.png");},
        function() {$(this).attr("src","images/about.png");
    });
});
</script>
```

place the class home in the `img` tag. Done. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 28):

As previously stated, no need for a JS solution.

Another way of doing it is by loading both images and hiding/showing them with the `:hover` event. Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="home"><img class="image_on" src="images/about.png" alt="logo" /><img class="image_off" src="images/aboutR.png" alt="logo" /></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image_off, #home:hover .image_on{
   display:none
}
.image_on, #home:hover .image_off{
   display:block
}
```

Comment: This works nice. Can be added there the width of the imaged used so the hove be more precise!

Answer (score 18):

Here is a js/jquery solution

```
//should go inside your <head> tag
function onHover()
{
    $("#menuImg").attr('src', 'images/aboutR.png');
}

function offHover()
{
    $("#menuImg").attr('src', 'images/about.png');
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menu" >  
  <a href="#" id="home">
    <img id="menuImg" src="images/about.png" alt="logo" onmouseover="onHover();" 
      onmouseout="offHover();" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5JGRJ/). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
#menu {
    width: 400px;
    height: 142px;
    margin-left: 353px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#menu:hover {
    background: url(lPr4mOr.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" id="home"><img src="lPr4m.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Image names changed for my convenience making the page.)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `<img  src="images/about.png" alt="logo" />` twice, once in the html and once in the css.  I suggest deleting the html and strictly using css background image. You don't need the z-index either.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `img` tag, and set the width and height of `#home` (and any other menu item) to the width and height of the images.

Also, set the content to whatever the `alt` of the image would be (for accessibility purposes), and then set the `text-indent` property so it's moved offpage.

Currently, when you hover, it's changing the background image, but the `img` tag is on top, and it always will be.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu" >  
  <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu{
  margin-left: 353px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
#home{
  background:transparent url(images/about.png);
  width: 400px;
  height: 142px;
  z-index:1;
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
#home:hover{
  background:url(images/aboutR.png);
  z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Even if I am specifying the width and height, the background is displayed **just for the text written inside a tag**

Answer (score 2):

you could do a:hover img{display:none} which would get rid of the img, idk about size issue bc  you didnt specify the sizes. if i were you i'd either ditch the img element, use it as background-image for a element, then change it on :hover. or if you want the img element, use the clip property following the same principles as above

Comment: Instead of `display: none` it should be `visibility: hidden` in order to preserve the size of the box since his width and height aren't explicitly given.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `position` rule while using a `z-index` rule. Try adding `position:relative` where you used `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

are you just trying to make a simple image rollover? without seeing a working example i can't make out exactly what you're trying to do, but image rollovers are simple to do with CSS sprites, no jquery needed and this makes for a much more bulletproof website. it also makes your website respond faster because the default and over state images are the same image, no preload code necessary.

if you need a mapped image (rather than a full swap out) this can be accomplished with a background image, a container div and png-24 graphics (javascript required to make png-24s work in IE6, but who cares about supporting IE6 anymore anyway?).

a good way to change out nav images without resorting to javascript is by using the background-position property, like so:

```
    // define your container element
    #nav-home {  
         margin: 20px 5px;  
         height: 15px; 
         width: 40px;
          }

    // use a descendant selector to style the <a> tag
    #nav-home a { 
         background-image: url("/images/buttons-nav.gif"); 
         display: block; // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!!
         background-position: 0 0;  // the first number is horizontal placement, the second is vertical placement. at 0 0 it is positioned from the top left corner
         height: 15px; 
         }

    // this is where you change the position of the background for the hover state
    #nav-home a:hover { 
         background-position: -20px 0; //this moved it 20px to the right 
         }
```

and your html code would look like this:

```
    <div id="nav-home"><a href="/yourlink/"><img src="/images/transparent.gif" alt="home" height="100%" width="100%;"></a>
    <!-- uses a 1px transparent gif to "hold" the place of the actual clicked item -->
```

your image would actually contain BOTH on and off states, like this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites_hover.gif then all you are doing is moving the image to one side to show the :hover state.  (code example at http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav). you are basically making a window with a container div, then only showing a portion of the actual background image.

also, stay away from using :hover on anything but an  tag as not all browsers support use of :hover on block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

And now for the simple way:

```
<img id=logo src=img1.png onmouseover=logo.src='img2.png' onmouseout=logo.src='img1.png'>
```

This HTML will change the image to a new picture on mouse over and turn it back to the first picture on mouse out.

Comment: changing from the id name to this also works without duplicating id's.

i.e. onmouseover=this.src='img2.png'