# Change picture when I hover over the picture's overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the specific picture that I hover over. However, each pictures is underneath an overlay.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886828/changing-image-on-hover) to change the picture when I hover over the picture itself. 
However, I only can hover over the overlay (parent div to the picture).

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".overlaydiv").hover(
    function() {$(this).attr("src","images/aboutR.png");},
    function() {$(this).attr("src","images/about.png");
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm new with Javascript and very thankful any help.

Comment: You should present some html and css to help people understand your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your picture is in the said overlay, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".overlaydiv").hover(
    function() {$(this).find('img').attr("src","images/aboutR.png");},
    function() {$(this).find('img').attr("src","images/about.png");
    });
});
```

This should update all `<img>` tags `src` attributes that are within the `.overlaydiv`.

If you have multiple image in your overlay, and each should have a specific "new" image on hover, you can add new src as attribute on each image tag, and change your JS to use this new url contained in your attribute to change the img src (instead of hardcoding new URL in your JS).

Example:

```
<div class="overlaydiv">
    <img src="img1.jpg" default-src="img1.jpg" hover-src="img1-2.jpg>
    <img src="img2.jpg" default-src="img2.jpg" hover-src="img2-2.jpg>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".overlaydiv").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('img').each(function( index ) {
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover-src'));
            });
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('img').each(function( index ) {
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('default-src'));
            });
        });
});
```

This is a bit more flexible, and prevent hardcoding URL in your JS. It's also make it compatible with multiple image, having different version on overlay hover.

Note that we need `default-src` attribute to be able to "remember" the original `src` to set back on hover leave (after hover callback, when user moving out). You could achieve the same using [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to remember the `default-src`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with *pure CSS* in multiple ways:

- Using `img` *elements*:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block; /* or "inline-flex", "inline-grid" */
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: Aqua;
  opacity: .5;
}

.hidden, div:hover .shown {display: none}
.shown, div:hover .hidden {display: block}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="shown" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img class="hidden" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" alt="">
</div>
```

- Using `background: url()`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/200x200), url(https://dummyimage.com/200x200) no-repeat;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: Aqua;
  opacity: .5;
}

div:hover {
  background-size: 0, cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

- Mix of both:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: Aqua;
  opacity: .5;
}

img {display: block}

div:hover img {display: none}
div:hover {background: url('https://dummyimage.com/200x200') no-repeat}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</div>
```