# Change image source when a link is hovered in another element

Tags: html, css

I have a homepage with 3 links. In a div next to it there is a default image. Is there a way to have a default image then swap it out when you hover over the links?

Comment: Could you add a snippet or show some example code you wrote?

Comment: Some solutions are posted in here, just needs slight adjustments to reference the link instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886828/changing-image-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`~` general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)  to target elements next to another one (siblings), although they don't have to be immediately after:

```css
img.default + img {
 display: none;
}

/* when hover link */
a:hover ~ div img.default {
 display: none;
}
a:hover ~ div img:not(.default) {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">About</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
 
 <div>
   <img class="default" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200"/>
   <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's a good way to think about it. Thank you again.