# Change input type image on hover CSS in JS

Tags: reactjs, jss

Is it possible to define primary and hover images for an  `<input type="image">` element in CSS in JS? I'm trying to implement a different image on hover, but can't get the syntax correct.

```
    margin: 40,
    background: "url(/btn_google_signin_light_normal_web.png)",
    "&:hover": {
      background: "url(/btn_google_signin_light_focus_web.png)"
    }
  }
```

Comment: seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886828/changing-image-on-hover

Comment: I reviewed the link you provided. It describes the hover event in CSS. I'm looking to accomplish the same effect in a React project using CSS **in** JS (JSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

IN your CSS

```
.yourClass {   
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("images/iamge1.jpg") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.yourClass:hover {
    background: url("images/image2.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for CSS, but not for CSS in JS (or JSS). In the format you provided, JSS interprets `url()` as a function.